# How to create Google shared drives from API, using a Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to create a shared drive (in google drive), using API v3 (through python client library "google-api-python-client"). Code below:

```py
import uuid
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

drive_metadata = {'name': 'Test shared drive'}
request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
drive = service.drives().create(
    body=drive_metadata,
    requestId=request_id,
    fields='id'
).execute()
drive_id = drive.get('id')
print(f'Drive ID: {drive_id}')
```

But an error occurs:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?requestId=905c4aae-0436-44e0-bb04-3728ee53342e&fields=id&alt=json returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.". Details: "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.">

The error is intuitive, but my problem is about the correct permission I need to give to the API user account, because:

- This user is not a personal account, but it is a Service Account, because it's used in an API which should creates a shared drive to each customer of my application.
- My company uses Google Workspace (for business), and my personal account have privileges to create shared drives (and I'm the GCP project admin, at this case). But the GCP console does not allows a Service Account creation in the company domain:

  - It seems that Service Accounts exists only into the project scope, so, it does not belongs to the same company domain. That is, service accounts belongs to "iam.gserviceaccount.com", and have no access to the domain's shared drivers.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Can I use Service Accounts to create Shared Drives?
2. If yes, what kind of permission (maybe, GCP role) the Service Account should have?

Comment: Did you grant the service account access to the domain, have you set up impersonation to a user for the service account?

Answer (score 1):

As DalmTo spoke, delegating domain-wide authority to the Service Account, and impersonating an User Account, wich has privilegies to create shared drives, then the API works fine (and better: all artifacts created with impersonation are shown as created by the impersonated user).

You can see how to do this here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority

Thanks DalmTo!